# How to maximize browser window using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to maximize the browser window using `puppeteer`. I tried below code but the browser is not maximized to full mode. I also did not find any function available in puppeteer library to maximize the window.

```js
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false , slowMo: 100, rgs: ['--start-fullscreen', '--window-size=1920,1080'], executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 46):

This works fine for me.

```
await puppeteer.launch({ 
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      args: ['--start-maximized'] 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

```
await page.goto("https://www.google.com")
await page.setViewport({
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080 ,
  deviceScaleFactor: 1,
});
```

you missed the deviceScaleFactor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Answer (score 3):

Beware that `--start-maximized` flag [doesn't work in a headless mode](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2500). Then you have to set window size, e.g. like so: `--window-size=1920,1040`.

The way you can do it is you define both options in config:

**config.json**:

```json
{
    "browserOptions": {
        "headless": {
            "headless": true,
            "args": [                
                "--window-size=1920,1040"        
            ],
            "defaultViewport": null
        },
        "gui": {
            "headless": false,
            "args": [                
                "--start-maximized"           
            ],
            "defaultViewport": null
        }
    }
}
```

and you choose which one to use based on an env variable - you can implement a tiny module for that:

**Helpers/browserOption.js**:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports = {
    browserConfig: () => {
        if (process.env.BROWSER === "headless") {
            return config.browserOptions.headless;
        }

        return config.browserOptions.gui;
    }
};
```

then if you set env variable `BROWSER` to `headless`, the concrete window size will be set upon browser launch, and if you choose to run your script in a non-headless mode, `--start-maximized` arg will be used.

In a script, it could be used like so:

```js
const browserOption = require('./Helpers/browserOption');
const browser - await puppeteer.launch(browserOption.browserConfig());
```

Answer (score 3):

`args: ['--start-maximized']` is correct way to open chrome in maximized window

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped `defaultViewport: null`

Answer (score 0):

I hope that typo I see in your code was made just in this post.

Chrome arguments are passed to the `puppeteer.launch` function as the values of the key `args`, and not `rgs`.

Also, in your Chrome configuration, I suspect that the flags `--start-fullscreen` and `--window-size` are contradictory.

Finally, you might be interested in the Chrome flag `--start-maximized`.

For a full list of Chrome flags, see this post by Peter Beverloo.

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem

My solution: first close or minimize the previously opened chrome window

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution to minimize / maximize the *actual window* **after** a *headful* browser session is created. This solved my use case to have the ability to manipulate the window state (not viewport size) after the initial window creation (`--start-maximized` is useless for me)

You must utilize a Chrome Devtools Protocol session, as [Puppeteer *deliberately* does not have native minimize/maximize functions](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2500#issuecomment-389724464). Note this solution assumes you're running puppeteer on a Chromium based browser.

Working demo using Node v18.12.1 and Puppeteer v20.8.0

```js
(async () => {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    // Chrome Devtools Protocol session
    const session = await page.target().createCDPSession()
    const { windowId } = await session.send("Browser.getWindowForTarget")

    await delay(1500) // Delay for illustrative purposes

    // Minimize
    await session.send("Browser.setWindowBounds", {
        windowId,
        bounds: { windowState: "minimized" },
    })

    await delay(1500)

    // Normal - required before maximizing if previously minimized
    await session.send("Browser.setWindowBounds", {
        windowId,
        bounds: { windowState: "normal" },
    })

    // Maximize
    await session.send("Browser.setWindowBounds", {
        windowId,
        bounds: { windowState: "maximized" },
    })

    await delay(1500)

    // Fullscreen - different from maximize
    await session.send("Browser.setWindowBounds", {
        windowId,
        bounds: { windowState: "fullscreen" },
    })

    await session.detach()
})()


const delay = (time) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, time)
    })
}
```

Note that if the page is minimized, you must switch the window state to "normal" before "maximized" to avoid an error. ([Chromium window state handling source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/854c948dff3246f5cf2a9368d7a1783d04f0f936/chrome/browser/devtools/protocol/browser_handler.cc#:%7E:text=if%20(window_state%20%3D%3D%20%22fullscreen%22)%20%7B))

I referenced [this article](https://www.lambdatest.com/automation-testing-advisor/javascript/puppeteer-createCDPSession) and [this puppeteer-extra plugin](https://github.com/Stillerman/puppeteer-extra-minmax/tree/24777f8d57ec624bf41f1ba7a275f43b95a142ad) to figure out the above solution. If you're inclined to utilize that plugin, note that it may not work properly, as it [only switches the window to "normal" mode](https://github.com/Stillerman/puppeteer-extra-minmax/blob/24777f8d57ec624bf41f1ba7a275f43b95a142ad/util.js), instead of "normal" **then** "maximized".